# How to set ''click'' as more important than Hover effect on Js and CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I set a toggle so when I click the buttons, the button gets the 'selecionado' class and change the border color. But when I hover and click, the color remains with the hover color until I remove the mouse.
How do I change it in a way that when I click, the color of the 'selecionado' class appears instantly like a priority over the hover color ?

[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1DC9.gif)

Javascript :

```
const botaops = document.querySelector("#IdProntoSocorro")
const botaoEnf = document.querySelector("#IdEnfermaria")
const botaoAmb = document.querySelector("#IdAmbulatorio")

botaops.addEventListener("click", function() {
    botaops.classList.toggle("selecionado");
});

botaoEnf.addEventListener("click", function() {
    botaoEnf.classList.toggle("selecionado");
});

botaoAmb.addEventListener("click", function() {
    botaoAmb.classList.toggle("selecionado");
});
```

CSS :

```
button:hover {
    border: 3px solid rgb(129, 129, 129);
    background: red;
}

.selecionado{
    border: 3px solid rgb(18, 101, 255);
}
```

Color of the click to be superimposed over the Hover effect at the time of the click !

Answer (score 1):

Increase the specificity of the second rule:

```css
button.selecionado {
    border: 3px solid rgb(18, 101, 255);
}
```

Comment: See the code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/6qa1u457/

Answer (score 0):

Add `:not(.selecionado)` to the hover selector so that it only takes effect when the class isn't active.

Note that a `.click` handler will only take effect when you *release* the mouse. If that's too late for you, and you want it to take effect when you initially press the mouse, use `mousedown` instead.

```js
const botaops = document.querySelector("#IdProntoSocorro")
botaops.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  botaops.classList.toggle("selecionado");
});
```

```css
button:hover:not(.selecionado) {
  border: 3px solid rgb(129, 129, 129);
  background: red;
}

.selecionado {
  border: 3px solid rgb(18, 101, 255);
}
```

```html
<button id="IdProntoSocorro">click</button>
```